# How to architect/annotate beans so they come from session after 1st time creation from persistence layer

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I am early in the architecting phase of a project -- there is no code to post.  Basically, I have a controller retrieving a "Model bean" which roughly corresponds to the page/form: so it has form information (what checkboxes are selected, etc.) -- and also contains domain beans (database entity info).

How to get Spring to create "default" info for the "model beans" on the first use, but retrieve from session thereafter.  And similarly, how to get Spring to create domain bean from persistence layer 1st time, but retrieve it from the session thereafter? *EDIT*: Using just annotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your question right. This is what I have done.

Under LoginController I have condition to authenticate user. Then I add the user info in a bean and `redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute("mySession", thisIsUserSessionBean);`

This is redirected to another controller called LandingController. Annotation under LandingController is something like below. Note: `@SesssionAttributes` annotation. You can add any information under this session object. My suggestion, keep the bean smaller for performance sake.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/homepage")
@SessionAttributes({"mySession"})
public class LandingController
```

I would not prefer to have domain bean sticked in session.